# ListObject contains extra headers after adding

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins, vba

I add a new ListObject on the worksheet starting from D3 cell and then create columns and bind them with XMLMap. Here is my code:

```
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = _workbook.Sheets["Data1"];
            sheet.Activate();
            sheet.get_Range("D3").Select();

            var xmlMap = _workbook
                .XmlMaps
                .Add(collectionDatablock.GetSchema(), NetworkTree.RootName);
            xmlMap.Name = collectionDatablock.Name;

            var listObject = sheet
                .ListObjects
                .Cast<Excel.ListObject>()
                .SingleOrDefault(l => l.Name == "ListName");

            listObject?.Delete();
            listObject = sheet.ListObjects.Add();

            listObject.Name = "ListName";

            var column = listObject
                .ListColumns
                .Cast<Excel.ListColumn>()
                .First();

            SetColumn(column, xmlMap, "Col1", "/Root/Region/@UniqueName");
            var newColumn = listObject.ListColumns.Add();
            SetColumn(newColumn, xmlMap, f, solution, "Col2", "/Root/Region/@Code");
```

And SetColumn method:

```
    private void SetColumn(Excel.ListColumn column, Excel.XmlMap map, string header, string path)
    {
        column.Name = GetColumnCaption(header);
        column.XPath.SetValue(map, path);
    }
```

This code work as expected on empty worksheet but if there are any data above table (for example D2 cell has a value) then the list table is moved up and D2 becomes the top left corner of table! Further more if D1, D2 and E2 cells have values then an extra column for table is generated, called "Column2". Seems Excel try to include all data from range above a table into ListObject. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I have to specify both `Destination` and `Source` parameters pointed to the same range.

```
var tableCell = sheet.get_Range("D3");
listObject = sheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType: Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, Source: tableCell, Destination: tableCell, XlListObjectHasHeaders: Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it will be probably necessary explicitly say where the `Source` is located otherwise Excel chooses the closest cells as source by himself. In the following code the `Source` is set to `Range[D3]`. Hope this will work with your xml data correctly.

The `Add` method has some other parameter `Destination` which seems to be used to specify the upper left cell of the table but I was not able to make it work with source-Type `xlSrcXml`.

```
listObject?.Delete();
listObject = sheet.ListObjects.Add(Source: ((Worksheet)sheet).Range["D3"]);
```